# How do I define a variable for all class methods use?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to define a variables that is to be used in all the methods of one class.

```
class A:
    def method1(self):
        for i in range(N):
            *do something with M*
    def method2(self):
        for i in range(N):
            *do other thing with M*
```

and so on.
All I need to do is define N and M variables somewhere in the begining of class describing. I tried to define it in constructor like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(N, M):
        self.N=N
        self.M=M
    def method1(self):
        ...
```

in tend to call A with this parameters just once. But there was another error in case I don't really now how to use constructor for now. Then I add this variables as parameters of each method:

```
...
def method1(self, N, M):
    ...
```

And that time it worked perfectly. But I don't want to input values each time I call A.methodX() and I'm 100% sure there is one or two ways that accords my requests.

Comment: seems like you had the right idea what using the constructor, what was your error? it may be fixable

Comment: The constructor approach is "the right way"™, what is the exact code you tried and the exact error?

Comment: @R Nar when i call A.methodX() it simply says that N is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track so I wrote a short version of what I suspect you wanted to do with a little 'debug' code embedded.  Note the instantiation of the class `aa = A(1,2)`

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, N, M):
        self.N = N
        self.M = M
    def method1(self):
        print ("iterate N")
        for i in range(self.N):
            print (str(i) + "\n")
    def method2(self):
        print ("iterate M")
        for i in range(self.M):
            print (str(i) + "\n")


aa = A(1, 2)
aa.method1()
aa.method2()
```

Note that what I've done here is create instance variables - you can also create class variables by instantiating them outside of the methods.  So iVar becomes the class variable.

```
class A:

    iVar = 0

    def __init__(self, N, M):
            self.N = N
            self.M = M

    ......
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You see, I'm extremly new in OOP and the whole idea was in using SELF.PARAMETER isntead of just PARAMETER!